# Five balls are to be placed in 3boxes

Tags: permutations

Five balls are to be placed in 3boxes such that balls are different but boxes are identical

Comment: Show whatever you have tried.

Comment: This is a _statement_, not a question.

Answer (score 1):

In first box, you could put any of the five balls, there are 5 ways to put a ball in the first box. In the second box, there are 4 ways. In the third box, there are 3 ways. So, total no. of ways to put 5 different balls in 3 identical boxes are 5*4*3=60 ways

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no box is empty.
Number of ways in which I can put 5 balls in 3 identical boxes are :
$$ 1 2 2 , 113$$
Number of ways to accomplish the condition is :
$$^5C_1 . ^4C_2.^2C_2 \ + \  ^5C_1 . ^4C_1.^3C_3$$
There will be no rearrangement as the boxes are identical.

You final answer is : $30 + 20 = 50$

Cheers!!